# See if any values match between 2 comma delimited strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

What would be the best way to return a bool denoting whether any values match between two comma delimited strings? For example:

> "1,2,3,4" and "2,5,6,7" returns true because both strings have element 2

ex2:

> "1,2,3,4" and "5,6,7,8" returns false because there are no common elements

Comment: So, you are saying that the following answer didn't help you? It's weird because it is exactly written based on your needs. In the other hand, you have been here for a while and based on your profile you are completely familiar with how this site works and how does accepting an answer works. So is there any reason that you didn't accept this answer so far?

Answer (score 5):

You can [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) your strings by comma and use [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. Like this:

```
var result = str1.Split(',').Intersect(str2.Split(',')).Any();
```